# Обрезание записи, вынутой из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Из базы получаем значение поля, которое по длине, к примеру, 500 символов. Нужно обрезать до 3-4 слов и вывести только их. Вопрос, как это реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решение mysql:
допустим имеем таблицу table и поле text тогда можем состваить следующий запрос:

```
select *,substring_index(text,' ',3) as text from table
```

здесь цифра 3 означает количество слов.

решение php:
$text - переменная в которой храним текст

```
$text = substr($text,0,strpos($text,' ',3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('#[а-я]+\s#iu', $text, $res);
for ($i=0; $i<=3; $i++){
echo $res[0][$i].' ';
}
```

Как-то так, разделяем текст пробелами по словам а потом в цикле выводим первые 4

Answer (score 0):

В просторах всемирной паутины нашел такую функцию на этом [сайтике](http://blog.ksdaemon.ru/tag/mysql-split-function/):

```
CREATE FUNCTION `SPLIT_STRING`
(    str VARCHAR(2000),
     delim VARCHAR(12),
     pos INT )
RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
COMMENT 'Разделение строки по делимитеру'
RETURN
     REPLACE(
          SUBSTRING(
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos),
               CHAR_LENGTH(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos - 1)
               ) + 1
          ),
          delim,
          ''
     )
```

Думаю, что можно было бы упростить, избавившись от лишних параметра `pos` и `delim`, решить вашу задачу для 3-4 слов. Либо пользоваться as-is.

Answer (score 0):

ну или такой простой функцией можно воспользоваться если считать что разделение слов может быть не один пробел, а несколько

```
   function cutstr($str,$cword){
        while($i<=strlen($str)){
         $char = substr($str,$i,1);
         if($char==' '){
            if(!$old){
                $n++;
                $old = 1;
            }
           } else $old=0;
         $cstr.=$char;
         if(intval($cword)==$n) break;
         $i++;
        }   
     return $cstr;
    }
    print cutstr(строка,количество слов);
```